# Disable parameter view option in BIRT Viewer

Tags: report, reporting, birt, birt-emitter, birt-deapi

Due to limitation of Birt parameter view we have implemented third party JSP to capture parameters and pass to Birt Engine.

But by default Birt viewer has option to see parameter view ( see the screen shot). I want to find a way to disable that option. Thanks in advance 
[image: screen shot 1]
[image: screen shot 2]

Answer (score 0):

After bit of a play around with codes I found the solution. The change needs to be done in ToolbarFragment.jsp , which can be found in the directory of

"birt/viewer/org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer/birt/webcontent/birt/pages/control/ToolbarFragment.jsp"

comment out the following snippet and your are done :)

```
           <%-- <TD WIDTH="15px">
                   <INPUT TYPE="image" NAME='parameter' SRC="birt/images/Report_parameters.gif"
                        TITLE="<%= BirtResources.getHtmlMessage( "birt.viewer.toolbar.parameter" )%>"   
                        ALT="<%= BirtResources.getHtmlMessage( "birt.viewer.toolbar.parameter" )%>" CLASS="birtviewer_clickable">
                </TD> --%>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using Javascript

> scripts menu
> client scripts
> inside you can paste the code below

```js
head.ready(function(){
document.getElementsByName("parameter")[0].parentElement.previousSibling.remove();
document.getElementsByName("export")[0].parentElement.previousSibling.remove();
document.getElementsByName("print")[0].parentElement.previousSibling.remove();
document.getElementsByName("exportReport")[0].parentElement.previousSibling.remove();
document.getElementsByName("exportReport")[0].parentElement.remove();
document.getElementsByName("printServer")[0].parentElement.previousSibling.remove();
document.getElementsByName("printServer")[0].parentElement.remove();
document.getElementsByName("toc")[0].parentElement.remove();
document.getElementsByName("export")[0].parentElement.remove();
document.getElementsByName("parameter")[0].parentElement.remove();
document.getElementById("navigationBar").parentElement.parentElement.remove();
});
```

[clientscripts opiton will appear here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTEZo.png)